# Could I create a file while setting Windows ACL

Tags: python, windows, acl

Is there an existing python module to combine the following steps:

1. Create a file
2. Remove all ACL
3. Grant domain Admin full control
4. Grant domain user Alice generic read permission

Expected: create_file(file_path, acl(entries))

Currently I create the file first and set permissions later.

```
with open(file_path, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(...)
win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo(filename, ...)
```

Comment: if you can call `CreateFileW` - you can do this when you create new file, for existing you need separate set security. but for what use `SetNamedSecurityInfo` when you already have file handle ? use `SetKernelObjectSecurity` instead

Comment: @RbMm According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/access-rights-and-access-masks, if I'm going to edit ACL on "Files or directories on an NTFS file system", it recommends me `SetNamedSecurityInfo`. `SetKernelObjectSecurity` is `Access tokens`. But I'm new to these functions. Any difference between these two functions? Thank you!

Comment: @RbMm Could you please give me an example on how to use `CreateFileW` to create a file and remove all the existing ACL but grant Admin generic read permission. Thank you so much!

Comment: `SetKernelObjectSecurity` work with already existing handle, so need use it, if you have handle. `SetNamedSecurityInfo` - if you have object name, instead handle. *and remove all the existing ACL* - if you create new file - of course not yet exist any security descriptor on it. you can pass  security descriptor via `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` pointer in call `CreateFileW`. but this is how i say only when you create **new** file. CreateFile ignores the lpSecurityDescriptor member when opening an existing file

Comment: As documented by Microsoft, generally we do not use `SetKernelObjectSecurity` or `SetFileSecurity` (obsolete) when setting the security of a file, since these just call `NtSetSecurityObject` (ultimately `IRP_MJ_SET_SECURITY` to the fileystem device), which sets an explicit security descriptor that will not propagate inheritable ACEs from the parent directory. To ensure inheritance, we use the ntmarta.dll function `SetNamedSecurityInfoW` -- or use `SetSecurityInfo` if we have a handle with the required access.